# Integrating $\displaystyle\int_2^3 \dfrac{\text{d}x}{2x(1-2x)}$ in W. Mathematica giving wrong result.

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals

I calculated by hand the following integral
$$\int_2^3 \dfrac{\text{d}x}{2x(1-2x)}$$

What I did it to use partial fractions:

$$\dfrac{1}{x(1-2x)} = \dfrac{1}{x} + \dfrac{-2}{1-2x}$$

Whence

$$\dfrac{1}{2}\int_2^3 \left(\dfrac{1}{x} + \dfrac{-2}{1-2x}\right) = \dfrac{1}{2}\left(\ln|x|\big|_2^3 + \ln|1-2x|\big|_2^3\right) = \dfrac{1}{2}\ln\left(\dfrac{5}{2}\right)$$

Now, checking with W. Mathematica (NOT W. Alpha) it does return the value of $\ln\dfrac{3}{\sqrt{10}}$

How is it possible? Even with some manipulation, the max I can get is $\ln\dfrac{\sqrt{10}}{2}$... Thank you!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You went wrong in the computation of the partial fractions. In particular, the sign in the numerator of the second summand should be positive.

Comment: Damn haha, thank you!

Comment: Moral: When something's wrong and you're looking for the error, check **everything**, including the parts you "know" are right.

Answer (score 3):

The partial fraction that you got is wrong.

$$\frac{1}{x(1-2x)} \ne \frac{1}{x} + \frac{-2}{1-2x}$$
Since,

$$\frac{1}{x} + \frac{-2}{1-2x} = \frac{(1-2x)-2x}{x(1-2x)} = \frac{1-4x}{x(1-2x)}$$